# How to filter a wrapper list using offset?

Tags: wrapper-class, pagination

i am trying to understand the custom wrapper list pagination and came across this post,

[Display more than 3000 records in a VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30351/display-more-than-3000-records-in-a-vf-page)

In this post, highfive given a method which is having a comment "Here use the offset variable to filter your wrapper list" in the generateYourTableContentList() method. What actually "filtering using offset" means here. Moreover my scenario is i am having a custom wrapper list and no sobjects, so i do not have a luxury to use SOQL offset. Any suggestions please.

Comment: why do you want to go for the OFFSET route when there are better ways using Visualforce, OFFSET has a max limit of 2000 which means you can only skip the first 2000 rows in your query.

Comment: OFFSET is a feature that is available in salesforce that will let you offset(or) skip the number of records you say in the offset number. check this out http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm e.g select id from account limit 100 offset 10 gives records from index 11 to 100.

Comment: Thanks rao. my resultset is wrapper list from a webservice call. so i am trying to paginate the list using pageblocktable.

Comment: Are you very sure that your wrapper list is not going to hold more than 2000 records, OFFSET can be set more than 2000 if not post your class, I will help you with your pagination logic using conventional ways

Comment: Rao, thanks a lot for looking into this issue. I got solution from Keith's blog. http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/client-side-sorting-and-pagination-of-an-apexpageblocktable/ Which is a excellent article.

Comment: Yep there are loads of info available over pagination :) good luck

Comment: In your reference link, I have used the `offset` for skipping the query results whereas it needs. Sorry if it mislead you