# Pagination - rendered is false for standardController

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I am prepared to be flamed for asking such a newbie question (which is similar to others) but I'll suffer the shame if I can get this resolved.  Since my background is mostly procedural code, I'm studying SalesForce's "VisualForce in Practice" and am coding as I go.  In Chapter 4 (list controllers), they have me list contacts and (supposedly) have Next/Previous buttons appear.

When I code the following, no buttons appear.  I know that the rendered is evaluating as false (because the buttons don't appear) and suspect that the code doesn't exist for HasPrevious/HasNext.  In the examples I've seen ([Display more than 3000 records in a VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30351/display-more-than-3000-records-in-a-vf-page/30356#30356) and http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2011/04/pagination-in-salesforce.html), they have a controller which has code for HasPrevious/HasNext. The book discusses a standardSetController but doesn't prompt me to write any code for it.

If I'm using a standardController, then shouldn't this code exist?  I'm not supposed to write an extension for this, am I?  If not, why do the buttons not show?

Thanks.

Mike

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Simple Contact List">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" rows="5">
                <apex:column value="{!c.Id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.LastName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.Email}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockTable>
             <apex:pageBlock > 
                 <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                     <apex:commandLink action="{!Previous}" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!HasPrevious}"/>
                     <apex:commandLink action="{!Next}" value="Next Page" rendered="{!HasNext}"/>
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
         </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of standard controller:

- [StandardController](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm)
- [StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm)

and specifying a `recordSetVar` in the `apex:page` causes the second type to be used. Listed in its available [methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) are `getHasNext` and `getHasPrevious` and these can be referenced without the "get".

When I paste your page into an org I do see the previous/next links. I get 20 contacts at a time - if you have less than 20 contacts the pagination may be automatically switched off.

To start with you do not need to write a controller extension: that is where you may later add custom behaviour.

Comment: To anyone who reads my question, I apologize for not doing the most basic test of all--counting how many contacts I have.  Sigh.  I have exactly 20.  :)  Mea maxima culpa.  @Keith C, I do thank you for the explanation about recordsetVar invoking the standardSetController.  Now I understand how and why it get used.  Thanks for the clarification.