# Pagination in apex

Tags: apex, soql, class, visualforce, pagination

I am getting an error of limit exception in salesforce for SOQL results more than 1000. I need to show 50000 records in a pdf page(may be in different pages). Can someone help me here to do paginations for the above?

Class:

```
public  class Attachments_11{
public List<attachmentCaseWrapper> caseWrapper= new List<attachmentCaseWrapper>();
public void Attachments_11(){}

public List<Attachment> getattachedFiles() {
    List<Attachment> attachedFiles = [select ParentId,ID,Parent.Name from Attachment limit 10];
   return attachedFiles ;  
}

public List<attachmentCaseWrapper> getcaseWrapper(){
LIST <ID> K=new List<Id>();
for(attachment a :[SELECT PARENTID FRom attachment where    Parent.RECORDTYPE.NAME='Professional_vod'])
{k.add(a.parentid);}

List<Call2_vod__c> listCases = new List<Call2_vod__c>([select Account_vod__c,name,Account_vod__r.Name,id from Call2_vod__c where signature_date_vod__c!=Null and account_vod__C in :k limit 10 ]);
List<Id> hcp=new List<Id>();
for(Call2_vod__C c : listCases )
{
hcp.add(c.account_vod__C);
}

map<id,Attachment> mapCaseAttachments = new map<id,attachment>();

for (Attachment atf : [Select Id,Name,ParentId from attachment where parentId in :hcp AND Parent.RECORDTYPE.NAME='Professional_vod' limit 1]) {

     mapCaseAttachments.put(atf.ParentId,atf);
     System.debug('keys in the map: ' + mapCaseAttachments.keySet());
        System.debug('list of values in the map : ' + mapCaseAttachments.values());
   } 

//for1

    for (Call2_vod__c c : listCases) {

  attachment atf = mapCaseAttachments.get(c.Account_vod__C);

      attachmentCaseWrapper cw = new attachmentCaseWrapper(c,atf);

      caseWrapper.add(cw);
    }

// for2

 return caseWrapper;     
}

public class attachmentCaseWrapper {
public string Call_Name     {get; set;}
public string accountName    {get; set;}
public string attachmentId   {get; set;}


public attachmentCaseWrapper (Call2_vod__c cse, Attachment atf) {
  Call_Name = cse.Name;
  accountName = cse.Account_vod__r.Name;
  if (atf != null) {
    attachmentId = atf.id;
    System.debug('***************************************************attachmentId : ' + atf.id);
  } 
}
}

}
```

Comment: Does this need to be displayed as a PDF on the web?  If not, you can always do "export details" on a report, work locally with the results, and turn them into whatever you need.

Comment: Hi Jagular! yes I need it in PDF and exported process will not work as per my req.

Comment: In all honesty, try changing those requirements for a more intelligent solution.

Comment: Sorry it is a mandate.@Samuel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "1000 records limit" is a limit on the size of a list that is displayed in VisualForce. The workaround for this is to make lots of lists that are 1000 items long, and add them to a list of their own. You can then display up to the maximum 50,000 records that the query can retrieve, all in one hit. As the code below builds its lists direct from the query, it doesn't run up against the 10,000 limit on the size of a list that's not referenced in VisualForce. It actually creates a list of 50 lists, with each inner list being 1000 items long.

```
list<list<Contact>> listOfLists = new list<list<Contact>>();
list<Contact> listOfContacts = new list<Contact>();
for (Contact c : [SELECT Name FROM Contact LIMIT 50000] )
{
    if (listOfContacts.size() > 999)
    {
        listOfContacts = new list<Contact>();
        listOfLists.add(listOfContacts);
    }
    listOfContacts.add(c);

}

//and the last set...
listOfLists.add(listOfContacts);

system.debug(listOfLists.size());
for (list<Contact> cons : listOfLists)
{
    system.debug(cons.size());
    for (Contact con : cons)
    {
        system.debug(con.Name);
    }
}
```

Of course, the more records you retrieve and the more fields on those records, the more likely you are to hit heap size or viewstate size issues doing this.

Comment: Hi Dominic! Followed approach as you suggested. Now getting too many SOQL query exception 101.Please find it in the answer section.Not editting as that might be confusing for new attendees to this thread.Please let me know a way out for this here.

Comment: Hi Saikat. You are now asking a new question altogether, something like "Why am I getting too many SOQLs". There are lots of questions about this on the StackExchange already. I suggest you delete your answer, and before you ask a new question search for "101" and find all the previous answers. A clue is that you should probably not have a query inside a for loop. You need to do all your queries up front, then cycle through matching them up.

Answer (score 6):

The limit is enforced by the platform.  For pagination, you can use OFFSET in your SOQL, but this has a limit of 2,000 records.  You can utilize a StandardSetController as well, and this increases your limit from 2,000 to 10,000.  Other than that, if you want to paginate more then 10,000 records, I think you are on your own to try to come up with a custom solution.

You could likely come up with your own programatic functionality that is similar to OFFSET, but this would be a lot of leg work.

My advice is to reevaluate the use case.  The platform imposes this limit for a reason, and if there was a legitimate use case where a human would need to page over more than 10,000 records, I'm sure they would build a way to do it.  What exactly is the use case where a human needs to have access to 50,000 records at one time on a single VF page?

Here is some links on OFFSET and StandardSetController for pagination

http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/use-soqls-offset-clause-to-paginate-your-visualforce-pages.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096U2IAI

Comment: Hi sfdc_ninja! I have put my code. I am trying to incorporate your logic here.Can you please suggest how I can incorporate offset here?

Comment: Here's some sample code I used on a prior question for the user of Offset: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30351/display-more-than-3000-records-in-a-vf-page/40295#40295

Comment: If the use case is PDF then 50,000 records is not a problem. I'm pretty sure you can display all 50,000 using the method in my answer, without using OFFSET or creating very complex pagination.

Comment: Can Attachment support StandardSet Controller